# Can't enable list even with “enable run-stop” poke

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, microsoft-basic

Well, I've downloaded an old non-English textual adventure, which of course, "for the sake of professionalism" have list disabled. Even after entering pokes for enabling "run-stop/restore" and for enabling "list" it continually questions for an input (in-game). I've tried to enter listing even on starting screen but it regards an emulated "run/stop-restore" just as any other button. "press any key" (just in our language...) .

Link with downloadable .prg:

http://retrospec.sgn.net/users/tomcat/yu/C64/MiscGames/Html/BezMilosti.php

P.S.: Because of auto-loading of .prg format when dragged over screen in V.I.C.E I've even made a new .d64 disk and as such, provoked the infamous "Loading. Ready." state. From that place I've entered pokes indeed.

P.S. 2: I've posted a theme and thread about this problem under "scene" category on "lemon", the top-ranked site dedicated to commodore:

*edit (importing of the link):

https://www.lemon64.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=69043

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just load the game into VICE, dump the memory image, find the BASIC program in RAM, and de-tokenize it?

Comment: It would help us a lot if you phrased your request as a question.  For example, are you asking *if* it can be listed, *how* it can be listed, or to simply *show* you the listing?

Comment: I can't rephraze it without significantly changing a meaning...

Answer (score 9):

Those programs aren't BASIC<sup>*</sup>. Detokeninzing them with `petcat` produces:

```
$ petcat bez\ milosti-inst.prg 


;bez milosti-inst.prg ==0801==
 1991 sys2065 tmc

$ petcat bez\ milosti.prg 


;bez milosti.prg ==0801==
 1987 sys2065 fbg
```

So each of those prg files contains only one line of BASIC code: a `sys` instruction that jumps into the machine code part of the program.

---

<sup>* or if they were originally written in BASIC [they were compiled](http://commodore.software/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&view=category&catid=53&Itemid=126), and so the original source/tokens have been replaced by machine code</sup>

Comment: Thanx a lot for a link & info...

Answer (score 4):

[Laurence Gosalves's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7585/6527) is correct insofar as your game, *Bez Milosti*, is concerned, since it looks like the game is written either in machine language or in compiled BASIC.  However, not all text adventures which, when listed, simply show an `SYS` command, are like this.  Sometimes the game really is distributed as interpreted BASIC, the source code for which is initially hidden but gets decrypted or decompressed by a short machine-language routine.

You can verify this for a given game by `LOAD`ing (but not `RUN`ning) it, `LIST`ing it, and then using a machine-language monitor (such as the one built into VICE) to disassemble the memory starting at the `SYS` address.  Or, even if (like me) you're not adept at reading 6502 assembly language, you can try `RUN`ning the game and then dumping memory at $0801, which is the start of BASIC.  If you see what looks like variable names and the contents of strings or `REM`arks, then the game is indeed decrypted or decompressed BASIC.  At this point you can use the monitor to re-enable the <kbd>RUN/STOP</kbd> key (`> 0328 ED` in the VICE monitor), use that key to stop the program, and then `LIST` or `SAVE` it to disk.  (Note that many such programs also disable the `LIST` command, so you may need to first re-enable it with `> 0307 A7` from the monitor or `POKE 775,167` from BASIC.)

An example of a commercially distributed BASIC game that uses this compression technique is [*Tombs of Xeiops*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpezzHDSDs4). If you `LIST` the game after `LOAD`ing, all you see is this:

```
239 SYS2061
```

However, after running the game, and then re-enabling <kbd>RUN/STOP</kbd> and `LIST` via the VICE monitor, the game can be stopped and listed:

```
BREAK IN 3054
READY.
LIST

1 GOSUB 3150:CR$=CHR$(13):CP=1
2 GOSUB 2230:VA$="IT LOOKS VALUABLE TO ME":FC$="THE CAT IS FRIGHTENED"
3 I1$="YOU NEED A DIRECT OBJECT":S3$="I DON'T KNOW THAT WORD"
4 S1$="I CAN'T SEE IT HERE":IM$="THAT'S IMPOSSIBLE":WD$="IT IS NOW PITCH DARK"
5 W1$="THE LIZARD SEES THE CAT AND FLEES":SR$="A SILKEN BELT FALLS AT YOUR FEET"
6 GOSUB 5000
7 IFKTTHENOB%(29,0)=CP:IFCP=6THENKT=0
8 IFKTTHENPRINT"{DOWN}THE WATCHER OF THE TOMBS FOLLOWS YOU"
10 GOSUB 390
11 IFN1$="DESERT"ORN1$="SAND"THENPRINT"IT'S JUST A LOT OF SAND":GOTO10
⋮
```